# Get page number of a text for creating index in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am generating a Microsoft world document from c# console application where I have list of horses spread in word document in different places.

I want to display all horse names in ascending order at start or end of document as INDEX, where in front of each horse a page number should be displayed. I am not able to get any idea of retrieving page number.

Comment: Do you need any more input, or did you find another solution that you might want to share with the community? Otherwise, I believe you have an answer, which unfortunately points out the challenge that specific prerequisites (e.g., layout) are not so easy if you need to do them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

An application (e.g., Microsoft Word) that paginates a document inserts `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` elements (`LastRenderedPageBreak` instances) at the end of each page. To determine the page number of a `w:p` element (`Paragraph` instance) or another Open XML element, you need to count the number of `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` elements coming before each relevant `w:p` (or other) element. The page number of that element would then be the number of preceding `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` elements plus one.

**Update 2019-12-19**

In the absence of an application (such as Microsoft Word) that paginates your document, you must paginate the document yourself and add those `w:lastRenderedPageBreak` elements. Once that is done, you would determine the page number exactly as described above. There is no other way.

Comment: Hi Thomas, this gives me only page breaks count that i in the template set but when my data is put into document then it exceeds to like 11 pages but mainXDoc.Descendants(W.lastRenderedPageBreak).Count() gives me only 4 records. 

so i think page numbers are allocated only when i open document and that does not help me.

Comment: If you can't rely on the fact that Microsoft Word or any other application has paginated the document for you, you will have to paginate that document yourself. This means you have to write a layout engine that does that. Note that this is a **very complex** undertaking that can easily take a couple of months to do (unless you can make simplifying assumptions in your specific use case).